# phone gap app starts and just quits

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I have this phone gap app i created, and i am getting a strange issue now, and spent a couple of hours finding it but had no luck.

i am using an ipad 2 to test this,

when i build the app and run it in xcode the app installs in the ipad and then it opens

but when it loads the app (which hide the first screen) it just quits and goes back to the ipad's home screen.

then when I click on the app's icon and load it again it works fine

the most annoying thing is that the xcode console doesnt print any errors, if i can get any error messages it will be great too, help there is needed as well

any idea of why this can happen? any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: there might be a memory issue any memory warnings ?

Comment: There aren't any crash logs? In Xcode, open the Organizer, click "Devices". Then click "Device logs" below your device name.

Comment: well yes this is the error log you http://pastebin.com/EBci4q8X

Comment: Did you try debugging the application in device in developer profile ? Does the application run in simulator ? Try debugging it putting breakpoint in - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{} method.

Comment: @utsabiem I didnt understand what you meant, and it works on the simulator.

Comment: @utsabiem when I add a breakpoint i get this http://pastebin.com/fkxVXVjZ

Comment: @nivanka: The console log you've posted isn't a device/crash log. Please go the organizer and look for the "Device Logs" as I described. Are there any log files?

Answer (score 0):

i had to change edit schemes to debug instead of release for this and it worked a charm!

thanks for your help

Comment: Erm, this isn't a solution. You don't want to ship a debug build to the App Store.

Comment: I was testing it in my ipad, and got the error. and it was i as building a distribution version but used it in an adhoc environment. thanks for you help mate!